# Link two DOOR's modules without programming

Tags: module, one-to-many, linkage, requirements, ibm-doors

I am new with IBM DOORS and I need some hint or help with this, probably, basic issue.

I have a **Module A** which contains some requirements and another **Modules B,C,D etc**, which corresponds to a concrete supplier answering to requirements that come from Module A. Therefore, if a requirement changes (i.e the text) I would like that automatically that change is also shown in modules B,C D...

**Module A** (Atributes)
Req_code (text)
Req_type
Req_text
Req_owner
[...]

**Module B,C..** (Atributes)
Req_code (text)
Supplier
Base_option
Req_answer
Req_comments
[...]

The idea is, somehow, to make a linkage between *Req_code* in Module A and *Req_code* from other modules (one to many) so I can create a complete view with atributes from two modules.

I have been searching on the web but I have only found that this could be done with a dxl script. Is there any other way to do this not involving programming? I tried creating a linkage module, but I did not get what I wanted.

Thanks in advance,
Bilbinight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is actually the companion of link-by-attribute; Link > Advanced > Create links..., but first lets do a little architecture creation.

I am assuming that B, C, etc. will be creating answers to A and, as such, will be doing the linking to the objects in A as they answer. With this information, we can create Module A with Req_code (use "Object Identifier"), Req_type (Type:string or enumerated list), Req_text (Use "Object Text"), Req_owner (Type:string), etc.

Similarly, create Modules B and C with such attributes as necessary to describe the information to be contained in them. finally create a link module "L" to contain the Link Sets for B->A and C->A. note the link module contains only link sets, not actual links. the links are stored in the source modules, i.e., Modules B and C.

Just to be safe,  I would also go to File > Module Properties... select Linksets tab and set linksets in each of B and C to A through link Module L. Make mandatory and Only allow outgoing links... at the bottom.

Now we are ready to create objects in A (Insert > Object). Create some requirement text in the "Object Text" attribute or any other attributes that you want to appear in the other modules.

go to B and create an object. Link > Start Link go to the Object in A you want to link to and select Link > Make Link from Start. (It may ask the first time if you want to create a link set, just say Yes.) a little orange outgoing, and yellow incoming triangle will appear on each corresponding object.

finally, in B Analysis > Wizard... choose Out-links, DOORS links only; Next> (since we only have one anyway) choose All (formal) modules and All (Link) Modules; Next>
(choose the attributes you want to display from the other module) Next> (make sure Recursive analysis is not checked) and Finish.

This will create another column in Module B with the attributes you want to display from Module A.

You can now go to View > Save As... and give the view a name and at any time, see the linked information from Module B.

The only DXL that was written here was the DXL you wrote when you ran the Wizard.

WOW! A whole free training module in how to use DOORS!

Comment: Don Fowler, thanks a lot for your time, I really appreciate your explanation (clear and easy to understand). Just one questions. 1) I would like Req_code to be a number I establish. I think that if I use object identifier this number is autoincremental and I cannot define it the way I want. Is there an option to link both modules by a text attribute different from object identifier

Comment: Yes, The attribute just needs to be unique. ABC-123 needs to occur only once in the module being linked to. you can link multiple objects to ABC-123, just that it is unique.-- Just curious, why would you not want to use the Absolute Number attribute which is guaranteed to be unique. Generally the reason a different attribute is used is because of legacy. a document was created with manually generated requirement numbers and they needed to be preserved for the ages.

Comment: In module A, the Req_code (i.e ABC-001, ABC-002...) will be unique. In module B, instead, one Req_code could appear more than once. I thought that as objects are inserted in module B and an Object identifier is given to each row, there was no problem of repeating Req_code and using it as a linker to module A. But when I try to do this it says that the link could not be done because ABC-001 was not found in Module A (I guess because DOORs is looking for ABC-001 in Moduel A's Object Identifier attribute and not in Req_Code).

Comment: I just looked, and yes, you are correct. The out-of-the-box Link by attribute is looking for the text attribute in Module B with the Absolute Number of the object in Module A. What you are wanting to do is possible to do in DXL, by basically rewriting the tool to look in a different attribute, but would require on the order of 20 to 30 lines of code. I've written similar code, but what I would recommend is to simply note the Absolute Number attribute in Module A and put that into a text attribute in Module B, or better, create the link as you go to prevent any mistakes.

Comment: Yes, I would do it that way. Thanks again for your time and your support =)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to investigate the 'Link by Attribute' tool under the Link - Advanced menu. This is on DOORS 9.6.1.10, though most 9.x should have the same.

You will be able to create links between two modules, matching up a particular attribute- and then repeating the process for each subsequent module you need to link to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Russell. Yes, I found that option but I am not sure if both modules should be completed with objects in order to do the linkage or if it is possible to do it even if no object is inserted in any module. I come from SQL and DOORS is not so clear for me.